# Q: prove $ |\int_{A}^{B}\frac{\sin x}{x} | \leq \frac{2}{A}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to prove that:

for $0 < A<B<\infty$

$$\left |\int_{A}^{B}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx  \right |  \leq  \frac{2}{A}$$

I managed to prove that $\int_{A}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx \leq  \frac{1}{A}$ but it didn't help me much.

Comment: Hint: try using integration by parts.

Comment: You could replace $B$ by $\infty$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng That's not a priori clear. The integral from $A$ to $\infty$ can be zero while the integral from $A$ to some $B>A$ needn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ A,B\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} $, we have :

$$\int_{A}^{B}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\cos{A}}{A}-\frac{\cos{B}}{B}-\int_{A}^{B}{\frac{\cos{x}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}$$

Thus :

\begin{aligned}\left|\int_{A}^{B}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\right|&=\left|\frac{\cos{A}}{A}-\frac{\cos{B}}{B}-\int_{A}^{B}{\frac{\cos{x}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}\right|\\ &\leq\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+\int_{A}^{B}{\left|\frac{\cos{x}}{x^{2}}\right|\mathrm{d}x}\\ \left|\int_{A}^{B}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\right|&\leq\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}+\int_{A}^{B}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}}}=\frac{2}{A} \end{aligned}